# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined jQuery draggable + sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a grid with divs where I have to use sortable and draggable
When I want to sort them out I get this error

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>     at Function.camelCase (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
>     at Function.css (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>     at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>     at S (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>     at r.fn.init.css (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>     at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-asortable.js:55)
>     at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>     at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>     at Object.trigger (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
>     at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
```

I use asortable because the items I have absolutely positioned
My scripts.js

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  revert: true
});
$( "#sortable" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#sortable",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});
```

and my html:

```
<div id="sortable">

        <div class="div div1 ui-state-default">div1</div>
        <div class="div div2 ui-state-default">div2</div>
        <div class="div div3 ui-state-default">div3</div>
        <div class="div div4 ui-state-default">div4</div>
        <div class="div div5 ui-state-default">div5</div>
        <div class="div div6 ui-state-default">div6</div>
    </div>
```

I can catch an item but not change it with another because it pops up error above. thanks for help

PROBLEM SLOVED!!!
After many hours i sloved this problem. :)
These divs are generated by .append(), so i add line .asortable('refresh') to each generated div and it's working.
Working example (divs are absolutely positioned) scripts.js :

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  revert: true
});
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    var dataBlock = Mustache.render('<div class="module-{{id}}">{{id}}</div>',{id:i})
    $('#sortable').append(dataBlock);
    $('#sortable').asortable('refresh');
}
```

Maybe someone will use a working example.

Comment: That error usually means that you passed something else (not a string) instead of a selector (string).

Answer (score 0):

It should be defined like so. Where the div with id `sortable` is the container and the div with classes `.div.div1` are the draggable items. In your question it is making the container also sortable.

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
  revert: true
});
$("div.div.div1").draggable({
  connectToSortable: $('#sortable'),
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="sortable">

  <div class="div div1 ui-state-default">div1</div>
  <div class="div div2 ui-state-default">div2</div>
  <div class="div div3 ui-state-default">div3</div>
  <div class="div div4 ui-state-default">div4</div>
  <div class="div div5 ui-state-default">div5</div>
  <div class="div div6 ui-state-default">div6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, But I solved the problem, I added a solution to the post